# Importing function from file inside loop, and updating the function on every iteration

Tags: python, function, import

The problem I am trying to solve is the following:

I have a list of maps, and each map has on particular value which is a string representing python code. Inside this python code a list is initialized which I need to extract for every entry in the list of maps.

I tried to solve the issue by looping over the list and extracting the string containing the python code on each iteration. This code I then edited slightly on each time to remove irrelevant parts, and to make it a function returning the list I need. Once the code is edited it is written to a temporary python file which I use to import the function returning the list I need.

Now the issue I am having is the following: After importing the function from the temporary code for the first time the function does not seem to update itself upon calling "import" again. The essence of my code can be written as follows:

```
for map in list_of_maps:
    temp_file = open("temp.py", "w")
    code = map['key']
    #remove unneeded parts from code string
    ...
    temp_file.write("def getList():")
    for line in code.splitlines():
        temp_file.write("\t" + line)
    temp_file.close()

    from temp import getList
    print getList()
```

So it seems that once I call "from temp import getList" for the first time this function becomes fixed and is no longer updated on the next iterations. Does anyone know a way to make sure the function will be updated, i.e overwrite the previous definition? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You might want to look at `exec`/`eval`... but without knowing why you're doing this it's hard to suggest anything further.

Comment: @Chris_rands: Thanks for referring me to the question you mention, I didn't manage to find it earlier. After looking at it I still do not understand however how to use this "reload" statement to redefine my function.

Comment: Why do you think you need to redefine this function each time? It's pretty much an anti-pattern...

Comment: @Jon Clements: The reason I do this is that I have the list of maps as described in my answer (this is given by a software package I have to use to extract info from a website used in an experiment I work on) and that I need to extract the arrays I mention from this list. These arrays are defined and initialized inside python codes stored as a string every map entry of the list I have available. If there are better ways to deal with this problem I am all ears.

Comment: Instead of writing the python code to a file and then importing it, call `eval` on the python code instead (as suggested by @JonClements).  The `import` probably only works once because python thinks it has already imported the file since you use the same file name each time.

Comment: Ok I tried this, this seems to solve my issue. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Might want to consider getting those lists in a saner format, or pre-parsing to get all those lists and put it in a more easily accessible format where you can directly lookup and get the relevants lists outside of importing/eval/exec'ing...

Comment: The issue is that the list I am trying to extract is computed inside the python code I have as a string and that knowing its value without running the code is not straightforward.